# What's the point of std::launch::deferred?

Tags: c++11, concurrency

The whole point of `std::async` is to run your tasks asynchronously whenever possible. I would guess it's ok to not specify the launch policy and let the implementation decide (for example if there are too many threads in flight), but what's the use of setting the policy to `deferred` explicitly when launching `std::async`?

Comment: deferred allows you to use the same workflow as for multithreaded code, but stay within a single thread. Imagine a situation when user of your program limited number of threads available to the to just one. But even in the case of a single thread you need only one version of code

Comment: `deferred` also allows you to do lazy computing, wherein a system can set up a computation for another component that may or may not be needed, and the cost of computing it is not paid until it's determined that you actually do need it.